# how to mark the x axis more than 8 points in pyplot polar

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to mark my plot as 24 hours and i need to mark every hour.
I tried the following code, but the plot only divide into 8 and only mark upto 7.

```
theta = np.arange(0, 360 + 360 / 144, 360 / 144) * np.pi / 180
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True)
ax1.set_ylim(0, 4000)
ax1.set_yticks(device_dict[name])
ax1.set_xticklabels(range(24))
ax1.plot(theta, inter_data)
```

how can i make it mark all 24

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set everything between 0 and 2*np.pi like :

```
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True)   
ax1.set_xlim((0,2*np.pi))
tick_array=np.arange(0,2*np.pi+2*np.pi/24,2*np.pi/24)
label_array=np.arange(1,25)
ax1.set_xticks(tick_array)
ax1.set_xticklabels(label_array)
```

Is that what you meant ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


theta = np.arange(0, 360 + 360 / 144, 360 / 144) * np.pi / 180
fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_axes([0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8], polar=True)
ax1.set_xticks(np.pi/12. * np.linspace(0, 24, 24, endpoint=False))
ax1.set_xticklabels([0] + list(range(1, 24))[::-1])
ax1.set_theta_zero_location('N')
plt.show()
```

To get the following:
[image: polar-plot]